# Excluding a string in a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, I have some expression like that

```
expression1
expression2 expression3
```

I want to match "expression2 expression3" in a regular expression if "expression1" is not an unwanted string (Let me call it unwanted.). So, it should be like that:

```
unwanted
expression2 expression3 // Not Matched...

string
expression2 expression3 // Matched...
```

How can I do this? I have tried something like that:

```
(?!unwanted\n)(expression2)[ ]+(expression3)
```

But it doesn't work. What can be the problem?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: A lookbehind will work - [`(?<!unwanted\n)(expression2)[ ]+(expression3)`](https://regex101.com/r/DlJmPw/2). The question is, what is your regex flavor?

Comment: I'm using JavaScript which does not support lookbehind.

Comment: Good, now the question is, are you extracting or replacing?

Answer (score 0):

Capture the unwanted string into Group 1 and check if it is *undefined*. If it is, there is no unwanted text and you may grab that match, else, discard it:

```js
var regex = /(unwanted\n)?(expression\d+)\s+(expression\d+)/g;
var str = "unwanted\nexpression2 expression3\n\nstring\nexpression4 expression5";
var res = [], m;
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m[1] === undefined) res.push(m[0]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Actually, my concern is that the unwanted string should be 1 line above to the expression2&3 if it exists. That is, there will not be any other string between them.

Comment: That is not a problem, use `/(^unwanted\n)?(expression\d+)\s+(expression\d+)/gm` - this will capture `unwanted` as a whole line if present.

Comment: Can we make the result as a regular expression instead of an array since I will use it in a function?

Comment: What do you mean by *can we make the result as a regular expression*? If you need 1 single match, just remove `g` modifier and use `var res`, `res = m[0]` and return `res`. Note that there is no need capturing two parts with capturing groups then, just use `/(^unwanted\n)?YOUR_PATTERN/m`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could work on from this:

```
(?!unwanted.*)(?:^.{1,8}).*\s*(expression2 expression3)
```

Basically it makes sure the expressions are preceded by at least the number of characters in `unwanted`, that **isn't** `unwanted`.

If you only want the *expressions* you'll get them in capture group 1.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lMrPo1/3).

**Edit:** Looking at this one's I realize it's probably full of caveats, but it might get you started. (can't see them now though ;)

**Edit 2:** Alternative (better I believe) requiring *something*, but not allowing **unwanted** anywhere, on the line before:

```
^(?!.*unwanted.*).+[\r\n](expression2 expression3)
```

[Here it is at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lMrPo1/5).